Fantasy cartoon from the 2000s about a world where people have animal companions
I saw a cartoon around 2006-7, but I don't remember much from it. The details I know:

It was in anime style, but I'm not sure if it was a real anime
The story happened in a fantasy world, where almost everyone has an animal as a guard next to them. Kind of like the Golden compass.
The main protagonist is a kid, who inherited a bear from his grandfather. (I'm not sure of the bear, but others said it's a strong one)
I'm 80% sure it was aired on cartoon network.
It was a series.
It was aired in Europe.

That pretty much everything I remember. There was also a scene, which I don't know why, but stuck in my memory. Basically, the main character and another boy laid down in the grass, and watched the clouds. The main character said to a specific cloud, that it's a cumulonimbus. The other boy asked, how he knows that, then the main character said, that his grandfather taught him about clouds a long time ago.

Could you choose a more descriptive question title? It is clear that this is an identification question about a cartoon. Is there any way to put a bit more description of the actual film into the title?

It's Magi-Nation, Tony was looking up at the clouds naming them off in one episode. It aired like every single day in England. The bear you're thinking of is Furok, a big blue thing.
The Cloud episode is likely episode 10, "Cloud Cover".
